# Implementation JWT based authentication without Oauth and custom token scheme

Tags: express, authentication, jwt

I am working on a Web API where I implemented JWT based authentication. I am not using neither PasswordJS middlware nor Oauth protocol. Its basically JWT npm which I use to sign and verify tokens.

The whole concept of token are pretty clear, but I very much confused with the term 'token scheme' and cannot understand what it is used for.

What I would like to understand is: do I need to use some sort or custom 'JWT' scheme and validate it when token is send back to server for further requests, or this concept is used only by Oauth, and what I need is only send the plain token?

```
var accessToken = jwt.sign({
    userID: user.id,
    isAdmin: user.isAdmin
}, config.userSecret, {
    expiresIn: 600 
});

res.json({
    success: true,
    user: {
        id: user._id,
        name: user.name,
        username: user.username,
        accessToken: 'JWT ' + accessToken, 
    }
});


jwt.verify(accessToken, secret, function(err, token){...}); //throws error when token is passed with the custom scheme
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly what scheme you are using isn't that important in this case, because you are parsing the content of the *Authorization* header manually anyway.

Basically, the token is sent from the client to the server on an HTTP header called *Authorization*. In front of the token you put the name of the scheme. So the *Authorization* header might look something like this:

```
Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWV9.TJVA95OrM7E2cBab30RMHrHDcEfxjoYZgeFONFh7HgQ
```

*(The list of allowed names is [here](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-authschemes/http-authschemes.xhtml). For JWT it's usually Bearer. You are technically not following the OAuth 2.0 bearer scheme according to [RFC6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749), but it's usually called Bearer anyway.)*

You have to manually take the token (ey...) and verify it with `jwt.verify()` to get its payload.

```
const headerExists = req.headers.authorization

if (headerExists) {
  let token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];

  jwt.verify(token, auth.secretjwtkey, function (err, decoded) {
    if (err) {
      res.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).json('Unauthorized');
    } else if (decoded.role === 'admin') {
      next();
    } else {
      res.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).json('Unauthorized');
    }
  })
} else {
  res.status(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN).json('No token');
}
```

You can see from the example middleware above that I don't care about the *Bearer* string on the *Authorization* header, only the token itself. You could, of course, check that it actually was *Bearer* and not something else though.

So the moral of the story is that:

- You send the token from client to the server on the *Authorization* header. You have to set up the front-end so that happens.
- You prepend *Bearer* in front of the token (or one of the other in the allowed list, but bearer is recommended).
- You decode the token by reading the second part of the string that is on the *Authorization* header and then feed it to `jwt.verify()`.

See [here](https://jwt.io/introduction/) for more details.